# Constructor injection: How to reduce amount of parameters?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have service class which has 7 parameters in constructor. 6 parameters are of the same type but with different qualifiers and the 7th is some other service.  e.g.

```
public class MyObjectInfoService {
...
   @Autowired
   public MyObjectInfoService(@Qualifier("firstObjectInfo") ObjectInfo firstObjectInfo,
                            @Qualifier("secondObjectInfo") ObjectInfo secondObjectInfo,
                            ...
                            @Qualifier("sixthObjectInfo") ObjectInfo sixtObjectInfo,
                            DifferentService differentService) { 
        //code here 
   }
...
}
```

Is there any way of shortening it - having less parameters?

ObjectInfos are specified in context file. e.g.

```
<bean id="firstObjectInfo" parent="abstractObjectInfo">
   <property name="firstProp" value="Some value"/>
   <property name="secondProp" value="Some value"/>
</bean>
```

MyObjectInfoService class has methods for every ObjectInfo where every method handles some logic and then calls differentService's method with specific objectInfo as argument.

There might be more ObjectInfos in the future.

The only solution I see is remove all ObjectInfo dependencies from constructor and manually initialize ObjectInfo in every methods and call objectInfo's setters to have it in the same state (unfortunately it's a library class and has no constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public MyObjectInfoService(ObjectInfo[] objectInfoArray, DIfferentService diffService) {...}
```

or better yet

```
public MyObjectInfoService(Map<String, ObjectInfo> objectInfoMap, DIfferentService diffService) {...}
```

that way you can use keys to grab the required parts and error on any missing.

Answer (score 0):

I might argue you are replacing polymorphism with qualifiers.

Imagine instead subclassing your `ObjectInfo` into more specific types based on use cases identified. Then your "service" could become what many would call a use-case interactor or use-case controller where the `MyObjectInfoService` disappears in favour of `MySpecificInformationController` that accepts `MySpecificInfo` objects inside the constructor.

As a guide, accept no more than three parameters in a constructor. Human brains blow up beyond that, and code inside the class ends up reaching out to far more things than needed. Subjective this might be, but historical evidence on this matter is pretty strong.

Comment: Sorry I might not understood you. You are suggesting on removing `MyObjectInfoService` and Replacing with 6 different services for each ObjectInfo?

Comment: I am suggesting that `ObjectInfo` is meaningless. As a result of something very generic you have ended up creating them with qualifiers to somehow separate them (which is where subclassing is intended to disambiguate) and you have a generic service to handle all cases rather than specific subclassed services handling subclasses of your objects. I don't know what these `ObjectInfo` objects are - would another programmer coming to the code instantly understand what is happening or would you need to explain things? That's a good litmus test...

Comment: The thing is that every `ObjectInfo` contain unique pre-populated data which is specified in `applicationContext.xml`. So either I specify them as beans or I instantiate them manually in the code using hardcoded strings or using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or something. That's why I created separate beans for each `ObjectInfo`.

Comment: That sounds a lot like configuration data hiding within a class called `ObjectInfo`?

Comment: It each object contain a field like a header and a file name, where as their "parent" bean contains some boolean values and server address value. Object info is meant mean for like sending data to other server. These values are specified in xml file for easier change.

Comment: Without understanding on what property these qualifiers are disambiguating instances of `ObjectInfo` it's a little difficult to suggest an alternative. Be sure that trying to configure one service with lots of alternate configuration objects is heading for trouble (imagine hundreds). Perhaps separate the configurations into multiple xml files each injected into a subclass of a generic service? You might even get away without subclasses - just new instances of the service each with data from specific xml files.